# Jenkins Pipeline Examples for Selecting Different Jenkins Node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Our Jenkins setup consists of master nodes and different / dedicated worker nodes for running jobs in dev, test and prod environment. How do I go about creating a scripted pipeline code that allows users to select environment (possibly from master node) and depending upon the environment selected would execute the rest of the job in the node selected? Here is my initial thought:

```
stage('Select environment ') {

  script {
    def userInput = input(id: 'userInput', message: 'Merge to?',
    parameters: [[$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'strDef', 
      description:'describing choices', name:'Env', choices: "dev\ntest\nprod"]
    ])

    println(userInput);  
  }
  echo "Environment here ${params.Env}" // prints null here

  stage("Build") {
    node(${params.Env}) { // schedule job based upon the environment selected earlier
      echo "My test here"
    }
  }
}
```

I am in the right path or should I be looking at something else?

Another follow up question is that the job that is running on the worker node also requires additional user input. Is there a way to combine the user input in one go such that the users would not be prompted with multiple user screens?

Comment: `node(${params.Env})` should be `node(params.Env)`

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the environment as a build parameter when kicking off the job, and you have appropriate labels on your nodes, you could do something like:

```
agent = params.WHAT_NODE
agentLabels = "deploy && ${agent}"

pipeline {

    agent  { label agentLabels }

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following for scripted pipeline:

The code for selecting environment can be run on any node (whether master or slaves with agent running). The parameter can be injected into an environment variable: env..

```
node {
  stage('Select Environment'){
    env.Env = input(id: 'userInput', message: 'Select Environment',
                    parameters: [[$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', 
                    defaultValue: 'strDef', 
                    description:'describing choices', 
                    name:'Env', 
                    choices: "jen-dev-worker\njen-test-worker\njen-prod-worker"]
              ])
    println(env.Env); 
  }

  stage('Display Environment') {
    println(env.Env);  
  }
}
```

The following code snippet ensures that script would be executed on the environment selected in the last step. Requires Jenkins workers with labels: jen-dev-worker, jen-test-worker, jen-prod-worker) available.

```
node (env.Env) {
  echo "Hello world, I am running on ${env.Env}"   
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `node` wrapping the `input` step and save an executor slot.